# Redirect on specific date/time with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to redirect on specific date/time?

For Example ... what would be htaccess code for redirecting website on 30th July, 10 AM?

## Update

Here is my current htaccess code, where my requirement (see above) will be included

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R,L] 

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png|\.jpg)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.html [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this rule (you need to enable `mod_rewrite`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20180730100000
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20180730110000
RewriteRule ^ /other_page [R,L]
```

It will (temporarily) redirect to `/other_page` between `10:00:00 AM` and `10:59:59 AM` (**only on July 30**)

Explanation: `%{TIME}` value format is `yyyymmddhhiiss` where:

- yyyy = year (4 digits)
- mm = month (2 digits)
- dd = day (2 digits)
- hh = hour (2 digits)
- ii = minutes (2 digits)
- ss = seconds (2 digits)

Comment: Thanks it works! But now i have another problem because i have this in my htaccess: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: In index.php I have

 switch ($_GET['l']) {
  case "":
        include ('index.html');
        break;
    case "index":
        include ($_GET['l'].'.html');
        break;
    case "redirect-on-date":
        include (google.com');
        break;

etcetc

and now i get "The page isn't redirecting properly" error

Comment: (1) Just insert date/time rule between the first two and `index` rule. Note also that the two rules after `index` rule (4th and 5th) are useless because already matched in `index` rule. If you want to "hide" `.html`, just move your 4th and 5th rule *before* `index` rule (which finally should be at last position). (2) To what page do you redirect in your date/time rule ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible :

```
     RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} <201808010000
     RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} >201807301000
     RewriteRule ^$ /destination/url.html [R=301,L]
```